# magento pdf download for product

Tags: php, pdf, magento

I need to include a pdf icon within my product details page so they can download it as a summary, ideally using the print.css

Is anything like this remotley possible?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Magento no-route controller to pick up any files of type '.pdf' and then serve up a matching PDF file.
Generating those PDF files can be done on the fly with wkhtmltopdf - the Webkit renderer that does a very nice job of creating PDFs.

I also changed some of my template code to detect if the referrer URL was the same as the server URL. If it is then it is the wkhtmltopdf program and not a genuine customer. When this is the case the template code puts out the print version of the headers/footers and those include vector line art (SVG).

On the product pages, with a similar technique I included the hires product images. All of these come through quite nicely to the PDF as do brand specific fonts (that are installed on the server).

Clearly your solution will need customisation and testing, however, I think the effort pays off because people do walk into shops with printouts of products that they want.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for sharing this... I'll give this some research.